# Symfony 2 - Set UniqueEntity message

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 2/Doctrine 2 entity with a [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint. As show in the documentation, it should be possible to set a custom error message. I tied the following syntax, but that dose not work:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="Your E-Mail adress has already been registered")
 */
class User
```

What is the correct notation for the UniqueEntity constraint message? Or is the documentation simply wrong?

Comment: Should work. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: After clearing the cache it gives an Error 500 for wrong syntax in the annotation. The version tomas.pecserke posted works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use only fields option in this annotaion, it can be used as the default option (the only option without name). However when you specify additional settings, you have to specify fields property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="Your E-Mail adress has already been registered"
 * )
 */
class User
```