# FOS UniqueEntity in form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOS and I built own form to create user. I have problem with detection duplicate username and email.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
  @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="Your E-Mail adress has already been registered"
 * )
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

And nothing. I see:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'test' for key 'UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8'

I prefer error message. I try: [Symfony 2 - Set UniqueEntity message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221716/symfony-2-set-uniqueentity-message)

Answer (score 0):

Actually FOS Model User already have unique entity constraint for username and email. Please make sure your form's validation_groups is set to "Registration" or "Profile".

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_groups' => array('Registration', 'Default'),
    ));
}
```

Or you can set up your own unique constraint using "emailCanonical" field.

```
* @UniqueEntity(fields="emailCanonical", errorPath="email", message="Your E-Mail adress has already been registered")
```

Comment: I try too. But I used: configureOptions(). With setDefaultOptions() doesn't work. Maybe FORM don't see validation_groups ? In my buildForm is addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND) It has something to do? I work to symfony 2.7.4

Comment: Please try to set up FOS registration form validation groups in confirm.yml:
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            type: <app_registration_form_service>
            validation_groups: [Registration, Default]

Comment: confirm.yml ? Maybe config.yml? <app_registration_form_service> - what is it? getName my form? If it is, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, config.yml is correct. You should register your form as a service and put name of the service into <app_registration_form_service>.

Comment: Ok. Now, I think see the problem. My user form was subform. How to pass validation for the subform?

Comment: Try to add "'cascade_validation' => true," to setDefaults in setDefaultOptions method of your embedded form type.

Comment: Yes it help and solution problem. Thank You!